# Form Name not changing in template drive form angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

After array splice *ngFor not updating form input name.

```
 <div class="row p-t-20" *ngFor="let multiple_option of questions.options; let i=index">
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Option {{i + 1}}</label>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="multiple_option.value"  class="form-control" name="radioBtn_{{i}}" #radioBtn="ngModel" required >

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle" (click)="addOption()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1" [hidden]="i == 0">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle" (click)="removeOption(i)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
</div>
```

```
{{f.value | json}}
```

{
  "question0": "scascsac",
  "selectElem0": "radio_button",
  "is_other0": false,
  "radioBtn_0": "ascsacsac",
  "radioBtn_2": "asccscascssaccsacsscsca",
  "radioBtn_3": "ascsacsacsacsacsac"
}

addOption(){

```
this.f._submitted = false;
this.questions.options.push({logic : {}});
```

}

removeOption(index){

```
this.questions.options.splice(index,1);

console.log(this.questions.options);
```

}

I have replicated above scenario in below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzyfky?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You need to pass a new instance to the ngfor for cd tp work

Comment: input field name not changing after array remove or push value

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzyfky?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove name and add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"